# Error moving to a new fragment with NavigationComponents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

So, this is weird, I have 2 ways of going to Fragment B from Fragment A

First one is from a fab button click

```
private fun navigateToCreateTopics(){
        fab_goto_topics.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_destination_my_topics_to_destination_create_topics)
        }
    }
```

And I have items that has an edit button that also goes to the same fragment but with a bundle to edit those values

```
 val bundle = Bundle()
                        bundle.putBoolean("shouldEdit",true)
                        bundle.putParcelable("topic",topicAdapter.topicList[position])
                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_destination_my_topics_to_destination_create_topic,bundle)
```

Now, if I press the fab button to navigate without extras to the createTopics fragment it will throw this exception

```
Fragment CreateTopicsFragment{216b801} (69e0b0ac-1352-4daf-aa36-717c2f320cc9) id=0x7f0800ac} does not have any arguments.
```

And I dont know why because I'm not passing any arguments with the fab, and the line

```
requireArguments().let {
            ...
        }
```

should not execute since it checks for nulls and there is no arguments passing

Why this happends ?

Comment: The `require*()` functions throw Exceptions when their returns would be null. You want `arguments?.let...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`requireArguments()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireArguments()):

> Throws `IllegalStateException` if no arguments were supplied to the Fragment.

You'd want to use `arguments` if you want a nullable `Bundle`:

```
arguments?.let {
        ...
}
```

Of course, you can also follow the [define destination arguments documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments) and add a `defaultValue` to your `<argument>` on your destination:

```
<argument
     android:name="shouldEdit"
     app:argType="boolean"
     android:defaultValue="false" />
```

Which will ensure you always have an argument Bundle set and either `false`, the default value, or your own value.

This approach works particularly well when [using Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args), which would replace your entire `let` with type safe calls:

```
val args: CreateTopicsFragmentArgs by navArgs
val shouldEdit = args.shouldEdit
```

Answer (score 2):

try `arguments?.let{}` requireArguments internal code is  `public final Bundle requireArguments() { Bundle arguments = getArguments(); if (arguments == null) { throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " does not have any arguments."); } return arguments; }` ,it throws IllegalStateException